# WordPress ACF use HTML sign in table

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I've already asked [this](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/use-html-sign-in-table/) question on the ACF site but I never got a reaction, so I'm trying it here. When I add a ≥ symbol to a WordPress ACF table header and then save the table it just removes the table content on reload, I also tried using the HTML code instead of just copy and pasting but this results in the same problem. Does anyone know of a way to insert this special symbol into a table? I would just create a hacky solution that inserts the symbol into the HTML using PHP but the customer wants to insert it on multiple pages that change

Comment: Can you please provide more information? For example, you want to enable HTML for a ACF field or you want HTML for the database Table? Please be more specific and if you can provide examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my issue was because of database encoding, it should have been UTF-8. ACF didn't have anything to do with it, sorry :)

Comment: The standard for wordpress database, has been changed from utf8 to utf8mb4 - the new form can store any unicode charecter with it's 4 bytes encoding, insted of the old 3 bytes version.